# Qt: How to modify data records in 2 tables using sqlite database

Tags: c++, database, qt, sqlite

**Problem**: Hello, I am using sqlite3 database in QT. I have schema defined as follows:

```
table users:        table wishlist
------------        --------------
id                  id
balance, int        balance, int
savings, int        price
                    uid (users id)
```

The task is to make possible for user to transfer money between either his balance and savings fields and also be able to send money to his wishlist items.

For example: user opens dialog window, selects source of money, selects destenation of money, writes amount and submits. After submiting dialog window the balances in the main window are updated with new correct values.

**My thoughts**:

In my app I should be able to transfer money from: `(src -> dest)`

```
(users.balance -> users.savings)
(users.savings-> users.balance)
(users.balance -> wishlist.balance)
(users.savings -> wishlist.balance)
(wishlist.balance -> users.savings)
(wishlist.balance -> users.balance)
```

Users have items defined in `wishlist` with a relation that user has many wishlist items.

My idea is to create a dialog window with 2 columns and 1 field for money amount. The data in 2 columns should be identical to each other. User clicks of first column to select the source of money and second column to select the destination.

**Question**:
What should I use (model for data and view) to fill data in columns from separate tables and make it possible to simultaneously modify the balance values in the same table (users) or separate (users and wishlist) and save to database? Is it possible to fill view from multiple data sources and later be able to correctly save modified values? Is it even the correct way of approaching this kind of problem or I am missing some better way of solving this?

Comment: Could you explain what it means:
`(users.balance -> users.savings)
(users.savings-> users.balance)
(users.balance -> wishlist.balance)
(users.savings -> wishlist.balance)
(wishlist.balance -> users.savings)
(wishlist.balance -> users.balance)`

Comment: These are just money transfers illustration (not code). For example user has 500 on balance field and 0 on savings. He transfers 250 to savings and now he has 250 on balance field and 250 on savings.

Comment: What relationship do you have the tables? Why is uid an id of users?

Comment: every wishlist item has uid (id field of user) because user should be able to modify and see only his wishlist items

Comment: For example, a user with id = 5, can only add or withdraw money from a wishlist with uid = 5, am I correct?

Comment: @eyllanesc yes.

Comment: and users can have transfers between them?

Comment: no that is not necessary.

Comment: [QSqlRelationalTableModel Class](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtsql-relationaltablemodel-example.html) ... [Relational Table Model Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtsql-relationaltablemodel-example.html)

Comment: How QSqlRelationalTableModel is gonna help me fill data from 2 tables? From what I understand it may only help me show users properties instead of foreign keys from table wishlist

Answer (score 0):

I assume that what you need is this :

```
QSqlQueryModel model;
model.setQuery("select users.balance, wishlist.balance ... from users, wishlist ... where .... ");
if (model.lastError().isValid())
    qDebug() << model.lastError();

ui->tableView->setModel(model)
//QTableView::setModel
```

Is it helpful ?

Comment: I understand that I can query data from tables that way, but will I be able to modify this data in model and save it to database?

Comment: As what Mohammad Kanan said, Maybe QSqlRelationalTableModel is the best choice.

Comment: Do you want a editable cell of qtableview ? And update model automatically after edit.

Comment: The QSqlQueryModel class provides a read-only data model for SQL result sets